# SMD oscillator and decoupling caps placement/routing

Tags: pcb-design, surface-mount, layout, crystal

I want to design a four-layer board with a PIC32MM0256GPM048T microcontroller. All components must be on the top of the board. I tried routing OSC1 (osc in) and OSC2 (osc out) lines, and placing the load capacitors (0402 C0G) near to the crystal (18.432 MHz, 2520 package), but I am not sure that is correct.

The decoupling capacitors (and GND line) are also near to the crystal's tracks.

Will it cause any problem?

Thanks for the help.

[image: Layout of tracks on PCB]

[image: Artificial 3D image of populated PCB]

Comment: Is that the recommended ground layout for the oscillator? You may have issues with reflow soldering having such large heatsink copper areas.

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think so, the 2 ground pads are on complete opposite side so surface tension should be even.

Comment: Are you trying to create a ground island around the crystal? What's on your L2/L3 and bottom layers?

Comment: Microchip recommended guard ring around the crystal, but I think this is not necessary for four layer board. My stack up is that: Signal - Ground plane - Power plane - Signal. I avoid to route any signal under crystal lines. I don't want to create ground island around the crystal because I think it add more parasitic capacitance to XTAL pins, I want to minimize this. I tried to route crystal lines as diff pair to avoid some phase shift. I added some ground VIAs near to the load capacitors to minimize ground return current path impedance. I don't know that my design how is right.